# Why Google Static Maps API gives wrong image?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-static-api

I am currently using *Google* static map API for an *Android* application. For *Android* application it gives me the correct image but when I use the same url in a browser it gives me a [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UElaK.png) of elsewhere.

#### My URL:

```
String url="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?zoom=13&size=640x640&maptype=roadmap\n" +

            "&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:S%7C6.972491, 79.917473\n"
            +"&markers=color:green%7Clabel:G%7C6.962225, 79.894642\n" +
            "&markers=color:green%7Clabel:G%7C6.951713, 79.917323\n"+
            "&markers=color:red%7Clabel:C%7C6.912690, 79.908225\n" +
            "&path=color:0x000000|weight:3|6.972491, 79.917473|6.962225, 79.894642|6.951713, 79.917323|6.912690, 79.908225\n"+
            "&key=key";
```

---

#### Image I received:

[image]

Comment: Seems, you are using other URL. `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?zoom=13&size=640x640&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:S%7C6.972491,%2079.917473&markers=color:green%7Clabel:G%7C6.962225,%2079.894642&markers=color:green%7Clabel:G%7C6.951713,%2079.917323&markers=color:red%7Clabel:C%7C6.912690,%2079.908225&path=color:0x000000|weight:3|6.972491,%2079.917473|6.962225,%2079.894642|6.951713,%2079.917323|6.912690,%2079.908225` works fine.

Comment: yep. I think the issue comes with the other characters like( "" /n).any way thanks.

Comment: You are welcome )